# Set JTextField width to match width of JPanel

Tags: java, methods, jpanel, jtextfield

I'm looking for a way to set the display of a `JTextField` to take up the entire width of the `JPanel` that contains it.

The only method I've been able to find to do this is the `setColumns()` method combined with a `getWidth()` method called on the `JPanel` after the `pack()` and `setVisible()` methods are called.  But when I do this the `JTextField` ends up much larger than the `JPanel` that encloses it.  My assumption on why this happens is that the `getWidth()` returns that size of the `JPanel` in pixels, and the columns in the `JTextField` are all larger than a pixel.

I'm not even looking for the field to dynamically resize, just to be as wide as the `JPanel` at the start of the program

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of an appropriate layout manager...

Remember, it's not the responsibility of the component to decide how big it should, that's the responsibility of the layout manager, the component can only provide hints about how big it would like to be...

For example, you could do this with a `GridBagLayout`...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(field, gbc);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: So is what "grabs" the horizontal size of the panel the line gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;  or is the getPreferredSize() method called by GridBagConstraints in some way  --- btw thanks for the help this works perfectly

Comment: @chope_chope The combination of `weightx` and `fill` in the `GridBagConstraints`, these two automatically override the preferred width property of the field.